# Personal records management -blockchain usecase

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

i'm building a blockchain with following objective and have few questions:

usecase Name: DigiLocker

usecase description: Users should be able to store all personal records in thier own channel and share the ledger with different third parties(mostly organisations with users in them) as required to read and write to the ledger. for example, me as an user want to have my marks sheets in ledger and add my school peer to write or read from it.

CLient Application Overview:

Client application (mobile) should be able to do following:

1. as an invidual:

   - create a channel
   - add records
   - grant access to other parties to read and write
2. as a school

   - read records of a particular user and read and write

Below are my questions:
1. Heard hyperledger fabric is the only latform which lets create multiple channel. is this correct?
2. How scalable is the architecture if number of users grow and so the number of individual channels? any special considerations i should have.
3. any sample application close to this i can refer to?
4. and if i chose to go with composer, any samples?

Thanks,
Madhu Hosadurga

Answer (score 0):

On 3 (Composer): these are the sample Composer applications -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-applications and the Composer sample networks -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks

There are also tutorials from the main docs site -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/tutorials or the 'next' preview Fabric 1.1 GA based edition of Composer - try https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/tutorials (it is the 'next' stream and reflected in the URL provided)